# Which strategy to choose to generate primary keys in Doctrine to save data like events and log items

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

I would like to save in my application data about user's activity. For example, If user visits a shop, I will save "visit event" in database. The row could have columns like shop_id referenced to the visited shop and visitedAt datetime value. However, in Doctrine is necessary to have primary key for every entity and I am thinking about auto generated id.

I would like to ask you what is the best strategy? Strategy based on auto increment or uuid? I think that uuid could be great because I suppose that auto increment strategy could be slow.

Thank you for your advice.

Comment: Autoinc is built into mysql.  It is every bit as fast as any other approach.

Comment: OK, do you think that this is the best strategy for this type of data? These tables have often a lot of data so there is possibility to merge data from more tables in the future and so on.

Comment: I would be tempted to just make a compound primary key.  Assuming these records never need to be linked to another table.  On the other hand, an autoinc is simple and efficient.